# How do I send a group of contacts via bluetooth?

Tags: contacts, htc-desire, bluetooth, file-transfer

It's possible to send individual contacts via Bluetooth with Contact -> Send Contact -> Send contact - Bluetooth.

But I don't see a way of doing this (on the HTC Desire) with a group of contacts?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. You have to install one application from market. There is an option to send all contacts via Bluetooth or Email. But I don't see any option to send a group of contacts in Android system.

There is an application called [Go Contacts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jbapps.contact) with which we can group the contacts and send it via Email,SMS or Bluetooth. Its a free application available on Android market.